# Writing out a quoted variable

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word

I"m struggling with some code that writes out a VBS file, for a particular line that writes a file path which holds a variable.  Struggling with getting the double-quotes right and placing variable correctly.

This line currently works, but only if "C:\tmp" dir is already created:

> Print #PayLoadFile, "HTTPDownload ""http://host.example.net/test1.exe"", ""C:\tmp"" "

Instead of C:\tmp, I would like to write to user profile directory.  But I can't get the part to write out correctly in VBS file.  I'm trying this:

> Print #PayLoadFile, "HTTPDownload ""http://host.example.net/test1.exe"", ""Replace(myFile)"" "

The 'myFile' variable holds a string of the user profile directory ("c:\Users\John Doe")

It should print out to the vbs file as:
HTTPDownload "http://host.example.net/test1.exe", "C:\Users\John Doe"

But instead it looks like this:
HTTPDownload "http://host.example.net/test1.exe", "Replace(myFile)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the value of `myFile` into the string:

```
Print #PayLoadFile, "HTTPDownload ""http://host.example.net/test1.exe"", """ & myFile & """"
```